# How do I use JOINs in a MERGE INTO statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, merge

I have three tables I'm dealing with for a signup form: [months], [members], and [months_members]. That last one is simply a join table. They look something like this:

```
[months]
========
[id] INT (Primary Key)
[name] VARCHAR(50)
[date] DATE

[members]
=========
[id] INT (Primary Key)
[fname] VARCHAR(50)
[lname] VARCHAR(50)
[email] VARCHAR(300)

[months_members]
================
[id] INT (Primary Key)
[month_id] INT
[member_id] INT
```

So, pretty simple, conceptually. There's a set list of members, and they can sign up for certain months. The form that I have, which allows them to sign up for different months, actually lets administrators enter (or change!) all of the signups all at once. And so I was hoping to use a MERGE statement to get the data into the database with a single query, rather than iterating through multiple queries.

So here's what I started to write (even though I know this is not correct syntax):

```
MERGE INTO [months_members] mm
INNER JOIN [months] mo ON mo.[id] = mm.[month_id] 
USING (
    SELECT 1 AS [month_id], 1 AS [member_id] UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS [month_id], 3 AS [member_id] UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS [month_id], 4 AS [member_id]
) AS u ON mm.[month_id] = u.[month_id] AND mm.[member_id] = u.[member_id] 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
    INSERT ([month_id], [member_id]) VALUES (u.[month_id], u.[member_id]) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE AND DATEPART(YEAR, mo.[start]) = 2013 THEN 
    DELETE;
```

Hopefully that illustrates the problem I'm running into. I want to insert any new data from the `USING` subquery into the `[months_members]` table. And I also want to delete anything from the `[months_members]` table that is *not* present in the `USING` subquery -- but *only if* it corresponds to a month in the current year. If there is data not present in the `USING` subquery that corresponds to a different year, I do *not* want to delete that. I want to leave that historical data alone. So the `DATEPART` condition is the kicker.

So I'm inserting into one table, `[months_members]`, but I also need it to be aware of the `[months]` table. Is there any way to accomplish this? Or will I have to concede and iterate through a number of SQL queries?

Comment: I have just deleted an attempted answer I made. Thought I had it then realised effectively you want two "not matched" conditions in one query. I'm not sure how you'd do this. Is it really a burden to have one delete step, and one insert step (all in one stored procedure)?

Comment: Not a burden, but I was just curious if there was an elegant way to do it in one step instead. To me, that's kind of the whole point of MERGE syntax in the first place: to replace two queries with just one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a CTE in place of the target table (or a view). SQL Server can trace the updates through the CTE/view. Here is a hacked-together demo:

```
SELECT *
INTO #temp
FROM sys.objects
GO

;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT t1.*
    FROM #temp t1
    JOIN #temp t2 ON t1.object_id = t2.object_id
)
MERGE cte USING (
    SELECT 1 AS [month_id], 1 AS [member_id] UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS [month_id], 3 AS [member_id] UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS [month_id], 4 AS [member_id]
) AS u ON cte.object_id = u.[month_id]
WHEN MATCHED THEN DELETE;
```

Comment: If there's more than one table in the CTE, which table does it delete from on match?

Comment: Playing with the select list and the FROM clause shows that it takes the table from the FROM clause (just like with other DML like DELETE where you can actually write the join inline without CTE). I haven't seen this documented yet, but I'm quite confident that this is the rule. IOW I think this is guaranteed behavior that can be relied upon.

Comment: CTEs and Views are not interchangeable as the target of a Merge [apparently](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/30633/merge-a-subset-of-the-target-table/30653#30653).

Comment: I had never used CTEs before! They are awesome! Thanks, that did the trick.

Comment: I've never used CTEs either - I can't see how the above would insert the new values?

Comment: @JanineRawnsley it doesn't insert. The purpose of the code sample is to show how to use the CTE. The OP can now solve the problem without me specifying the exact solution.

Comment: @usr OK thanks, just making sure I wasn't missing anything. I like the solution, I think I will play with CTEs soon.